# allow only autocomplete values in textbox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

I  have few textboxes i need the values only in autocomplete.If a user selects from autocomplete & enters a text the autocomplete should trigger again. Can someone help me with the code please.

http://www.apsrtconline.in/oprs-web/

I need output like the one in the link.

```
$(function () {

    $('#<%= txtCompany.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "WebService.asmx/GetCompanyNames",
                data: "{ 'companyName': '" + request.term + "' }",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {
                    response(result.d);
                },
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 0
    });
```